# Alfresco: display mltext in ftl -InvalidReferenceException - Expression res.getPropertyValueByQueryName('t.cm:title') is undefined

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-webscripts

I have a *.get.js webscript which executes a cmis query and result is displayed  in `*.html.ftl`.

So far it works great with String/Date properties, such as `cmis:name`, or `cmis:creationDate`. But I'm not able to display title (`cm:title`) nor description (`cm:description`). I guess the problem is because the type of these properties is `mltext` and ftl wants to treat it some special way. Please note that I joined with `cm:titled` aspect, so it should be in the result. Also filtering by `cm:title` or `cm:description` works (by adding `and cm:title like '%test%' to the end of the query`).

The exception I have is

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException - Expression res.getPropertyValueByQueryName('t.cm:title') is undefined
```

**myScript.get.js**:

```js
var query = "select d.*, t.* " +
            "from cmis:document as d join cm:titled as t on d.cmis:objectId = t.cmis:objectId " +
            "where IN_FOLDER(d, 'workspace://SpacesStore/72525f23-5273-11dd-9321-e32454ebec2e') ";

var cmisConnection = cmis.getConnection();
var cmisSession    = cmisConnection.getSession();
var results = cmisSession.query(query, false);

model.results = results.iterator();
```

**myScript.get.html.ftl**:

```ftl
<ul>
<#list results as res>
    <#assign title = res.getPropertyValueByQueryName('t.cm:title')>
    <td>${title}</td>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Comment: The workaround is to use lucene instead of CMIS, then access to properties is slightly easier, like `${node.properties.description!""}`